# how to extract data consisting of multiple links in a column

Tags: python

Here I want to extract the information from the given links in a column.
I have attached a sample data snippet on the below.

[image: screenshot of the data snippet]

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: i need a loop code to extract multiple .txt links in column as shown in image which is present in csv file

Comment: I know what you need but we are not here to solve your problem but to help you to solve it which means you need to provide us something you have tried or something you come up with so far. This will help other people have benefit from your question.

Comment: Do you have this data in a csv file or what?

Comment: i have a csv file which consists of links

Comment: And you want to get to those links and grab content from txt files?